# XeLaTeX: scrartcl + \setmainlanguage{russian} = "LaTeX Error: \chapterformat undefined."

Tags: xetex, koma-script, polyglossia

doc.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\setmainlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}
    \section{Тест}
\end{document}
```

Output of `xelatex doc.tex`:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-russian.ldf
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babelsh.def))
No file doc.aux.

! LaTeX Error: \chapterformat undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \begin{document}
```

When I remove the `\setmainlanguage` line, the error disappears, but cyrillic characters also disappear

I can fix it by manually defining a `\chapterformat` before `\begin{document}`, but it feels like a hack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `russian` module for `polyglossia` has a part of code specific for Komascript classes; unfortunately, it issues `\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{...}` without checking it is defined (which isn't in `scrartcl`).

As a fix you can give a dummy definition to `\chapterformat`. Using `\providecommand` will do nothing in case the class is changed to one that supports `\chapterformat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\providecommand{\chapterformat}{}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\setmainlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}

\section{Тест}

\end{document}
```

The issue has already been reported at the `polyglossia` repository:

https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/210

to which I added a proposed fix.