# Acro package conflicts with something

Tags: polyglossia, acro, russian

I'm writing my document and I want to include a list of acronyms using `acro` package. When I try to compile it with XeTeX an error emerges:
`Command \sectionformat undefined.`

Here is minimal example to reproduce the error:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, final]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{acro}

\begin{document}
    Just some text
\end{document}
```

I'm using MacTeX 2019.

Comment: Probably unrelated  to the problem, but `hyperref` should usually be the last package in your preamble. There are only very few exceptions.

Comment: The MWE can further be reduced to `\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{acro}

\begin{document}
    Just some text
\end{document}`showing that `acro` and `russian` seem to interfere.

Comment: Although being about a different document class, the following question might be related: [XeLaTeX: scrartcl + \setmainlanguage{russian} = “LaTeX Error: \chapterformat undefined.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449877/134144)

Comment: `acro` loads the package `scrlfile` which makes `gloss-russian.ldf` believe a KOMA-Script class is used. `\noextras@russian` then does `\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{...}` which throws the error. IMHO this is a bug in `gloss-russian.ldf`: it should not test with for a KOMA-Script class `\ifdef{\KOMAScript}` but with `\ifdef{\KOMAClassName}`

Comment: I reported the issue here: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/325

Comment: I've switched from ```polyglossia``` to ```babel``` and it works. Doesn't look like a good idea with XeTeX, but it works. Thank you all for help!

Comment: BTW: this is fixed in current versions of `polyglossia`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it describes has been fixed in an up to date distribution.