# Package conflict between chemmacros and Russian

Tags: babel, chemmacros, russian, chemformula

I'm trying to set up my document with `chemmacros` package and it seems like it has a conflict with `babel`

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, final]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
    Just some text
\end{document}
```

When I remove either `babel` or `chemmacros` everything works just fine. Otherwise there is an error:

`LaTeX3: Command '\ch' already defined!` from file `chemformula.sty`

For reference, I use `XeTeX` on MacOS.

Comment: Would it be ok to use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`?

Comment: Avoid loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. They used to be recommended since a few years ago, they no longer are.

Comment: Maybe ```polyglossia``` and ```XeTeX``` is better, but here is the reason why I do so https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512929/acro-package-conflicts-with-something

Answer (score 1):

`\ch` is defined by `russian`. Just undefine it:

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\let\ch\undefined
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Will I loose some function from ```babel```? I've never used it anyway, but maybe it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Boiling the MWE down it becomes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which shows that the conflict is between `russian` and `chemformula`.
One solution is already shown by Javier which you can use if you don't need tha `ch` defined by `russian` (a symbole for the cosine function if I had to guess from the manual and the definition).

But since `chemmacros` does not have to use `chemformula` there is another solution. It can just as well use `mhchem` for its chemical fomulas. So this might be an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\chemsetup{
  formula = mhchem
}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

A third way would be to rename `chemformula`'s command since `chemmacros` only uses the internal command if available:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \chem { O{}m }
  { \chemformula_ch:nn {#1} {#2} }

\cs_undefine:N \ch
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The chemistry command from `chemformula` then would be available as `chem`.